# Execute javascript on href

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have an asp website and am trying to automatically generate some javascript. I have an ashx file that generates the javascript and then I would like to like to this javascript in a href.
I have seen it done on other websites but can't work out how its done.

The ashx file called 'Hello.ashx' outputs something like

```
alert("Hello World");
```

I am trying to execute this as below

```
<a href="Hello.ashx">Text</a>
```

How is this done? Is is actually possible or are other websites using some trick?

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to load the javascript file when the anchor is clicked:

```
function loadjs() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', 'Hello.ashx');
    head[0].appendChild(s);
    return false;
}

<a href="javascript: loadjs()">Text</a>
```

If you're using jQuery a better approach is:

```
<a href="Hello.ashx" id="hello">Text</a>

$(function(){ $('#hello').click(loadjs); });
```

To load it once:

```
var _myscript = null;
function loadjs() {
    if (_myscript != null) return false;
    _myscript = document.createElement('script');
    //...
}
```

Comment: How would I remove any old imports, as multiple clicks on the link cause multiple imports